# "System Resource Exceeded" When doing almost anything in certain DB

Tags: ms-access

I have a database with a single table that's about 2.5 million records long.

The filesize is 1.1 gb. When I open the table, after I few seconds a msgbox pops up with "system resource exceeded" and all the visible cells in datasheet mode change to the value "#Name?".

If I try to run an update query I get the same message. Compact and Repair also gives me the message, and so does an import into a fresh database.

Does anyone have an idea of what I should do? I ran the hotfix available on the MS website but it did not help.

This only happens with this databse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a fault in 32 bit Access similar to one I have encountered.  If you have 64 bit Access available, you may find that if you repair and compact in that, it will work again on 32 bit - until it gets back to the point of needing a repair and compact...

Also, if you repair and compact such a database in 32 bit Access, you are likely to lose some tables, even if it is working properly otherwise.